# The "Find My Mac" setting will not turn on, despite having gone through Apples instructions carefully... how can I fix this issue?

Tags: icloud, find-my-mac, find-my

I have followed [the instructions here](https://support.apple.com/guide/findmy-mac/set-up-fmm53101237/mac) to turn on "Find My Mac", but it doesn't work. I have a Macbook Pro 14 inch 2021, with MacOS 12.4 Moneterey installed. I alread had location services turned on, and then specifically enabled it for "Find My".

Now, when I go into Apple ID -> iCloud, and try to turn on "Find My Mac", I get a popup asking if I want to allow find my mac, and then for a second it says "Settin up..." ... and then nothing. See this GIF.

[image: gif of enabling Find my mac failing]

It looks like [someone else has had this exact problem](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253198831), so I tried the various things in that post. Namely:

- I rebooted and tried again
- I booted in Safe Mode and tried, but got the same behavior
- I deleted various *.plist files, rebooted, and tried again

All without success. I should note that I also have looked on my other devices and they definitely can't see this Mac on the "Find My" app. So this is a real failure and not just a UI quirk.

(**Aside:** Is there a command line command or tool to enable these settings? I ask because, completely unrelated to this issue and on my work computer, I was able to fix an issue where I couldn't enable screen sharing with Google Meets by running a command line tool.... but that tool was only for Accessibility options.)

Anyway, I know this is a long shot but hopefully someone is out there who eventually sees this and can answer. I'm going to try to call Apple Support tomorrow and try my luck with them. If I find a solution I'll be back to enlighten y'all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK! I got it solved. To summarize the things I tried:

- Reboot
- Reboot into [safe mode](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/start-up-your-mac-in-safe-mode-mh21245/mac)
- **Sign out and sign back in to your Apple ID in System Preferences**

That last one is what did the trick for me. I hope this help someone avoid hours of troubleshooting and time on the phone with Apple Support.

Comment: Done that, does not work for me

Comment: It worked for me. Maybe I jumped the gun trying to set up Find My before my apple account got fully integrated into all the Mac features. I signed out, then signed back in again and waited for it to fully set itself up. It actually asked me if I wanted to set up Find My automatically and it worked from there

Comment: Consider marking your answer as accepted if it answers your problem as you said. It avoids it being bumped by Community bot as unsolved.

Comment: This worked for me. I migrated to this mac from another mac using time machine few days ago, which was probably somehow connected with the issue. I even didn't need to reboot to safe mode, just signing out and in again did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I had to enable "Home" in **System Settings** > **Privacy & Security** > **Location Services**. Then I could enable Find My.

M1 Ventura 13.0.1

Answer (score 0):

The initial problem occurred because I had to sign out and sign back in to iCloud, so I didn't want to go through that again.

"I had to enable "Home [Kit]" in System Settings > Privacy & Security > Location Services. Then I could enable Find My." worked for me.

Comment: How is this different than the answers already provided?  It looks to be the exact same solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved finally dropping my other Apple ID account that had also bonded to my Mac.

I then logged in again with my Apple ID in my Mac, worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. When someone mentioned Home Kit, it made me think, because I had Home Kit enabled for iCloud but not location services. Enabled Home Kit location services and then it let me turn on FindMy, which is a relief because even though it *said* it was off, I was still getting notifications that my MacBook had been left behind at home, even though a) FindMy was supposedly off, and b) my home location notifications are off.